# Copy files to root and subdirectories

Tags: powershell

I have a files located in `C:\Temp` that I want to copy to `C:\test`.

```
C:\Temp\test.txt  
C:\Temp\test2.txt
```

I want to copy the files above to the root and its subfolders below.

```
C:\Test\Reports
C:\Test\Reports\1
C:\Test\Reports\2
C:\Test\Reports\3
```

I tried the 3 lines below but it only copies the file to the subdirectories in `C:\Test\Reports` and not the root (`C:\Test\Reports`).

```
$dir  = 'C:\Test\Reports'
$file = 'C:\Temp\*.*'    # <-- file's full path
ls $dir | ? {$_.PSIsContainer} | cp $file -Destination {$_.Fullname} -wi
```

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Then .. add a line which copies it to the root? `c:\test\reports` is not inside itself, so it won't come up in the output of `ls` listing the things inside it.

Comment: Yes, it looks like I will have to do that. Thanks for fixing my format and answering to me question.